# Should we allow video editing?

Tags: discussion

Per this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18466/how-to-make-the-rest-of-the-mask-transparent-in-premier-pro-cs6) it was closed for off topic but the concept behind Adobe software should be similar to solve since he was requesting a mask.  Also what is our take on After Effects? Do we allow after effects question?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, there is already a site where this is on topic:

[Audio-Video Production http://cdn.sstatic.net/avp/img/logo.png](https://video.stackexchange.com/)

---

Regarding the question in question: I spoke with the AVP mods and two of them said it would be on topic. However, it turns out that Morgan had already re-posted his question to AVP anyway:

> ### Q: [How to make the rest of the mask transparent in Premier Pro CS6?](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/8013)
>
> [image: avatar] I'm trying to highlight a part of my video. Since I'm totally new to video editing on Premier Pro - I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing that, but I'm using masks. I have a title sitting in video 2 row, in it a have a rectangular mask (100% opacity) I then apply a Track Matte Key eff...

Answer (score 0):

No. There is [a site](https://video.stackexchange.com/) for video editing, and we don't want to take on video production in general.

I don't know enough about After Effects to decide anything on that.