# New “Help Center” is Live!

Tags: discussion

You might (or might not) have noticed a new link in the navigation bar. The new ‘Help’ center has been rolled out and is linked at the top of our site!

The gist of this project is to consolidate the various FAQs, meta posts, and blog posts into a much more comprehensive, educational resource. See [Introducing a brand new, consolidated, Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center). This is an on-going project, so there will be many more articles and features addressing our ideas and concerns.

One of the main advantages we see for the Help Center is that it's very easy to link, so we should probably refer new users there more frequently.

This is also a great chance for us to review some of our former FAQ contents, particularly in the "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" page.

**What do you think about our current scope? Is there anything you'd like to change? Anything that needs to be added? What do you think about having some more detailed instructions about things like font-identification?**

Please share your thoughts and ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

Video is a marginal topic for us. Video techniques, equipment and direction would not be on topic, although when and how to use video on, say, a website or electronic signboard might be.

On the other hand, title sequences (Saul Bass was a graphic designer before he revolutionized movie titles) and motion graphics (After Effects, Flash, Adobe Edge Animate are three examples) definitely are in our purview and should remain so.

Answer (score 0):

Do we want "video" to be [listed under](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) "Digital Media"?

I think it should be removed since those questions [would have a better home anyway](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/585/8708). It's not like [video](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) is a cornerstone of our site, either: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video