# Mod Request: Update the Help Center and On-Topic Pages

Tags: feature-request

I see these:

- [New “Help Center” is Live!](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/603/new-help-center-is-live)
- [Proposal to update the FAQ](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/proposal-to-update-the-faq)

But the actual [On-Topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has:

> This includes questions about:
>
> - Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not necessarily the "how" in logo design, fonts & typography, visual communication
> - Web design
> - Layout and printing
> - Illustration
> - 3D graphics
> - Digital media
> - The identification of fonts, if certain conditions are met
>     (see our guidelines for font-identification questions).
> - Critique about special aspects of a design work
>     (see our guidelines for critique questions).
>
> but not about:
>
> - Simple "How to" questions
> - Brainstorming or idea gathering
> - Technical questions related to video editing software
> - Web site architecture and development
> - Examples: HTML that doesn't include CSS, server-side issues
> - Landscaping and architecture

## Proposal

Change "Technical questions related to video editing software" to simply "Video Production questions", per [Should we allow video editing?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/585/should-we-allow-video-editing)

Change 3D graphics from questions that are on-topic to off-topic, per [Are we going to allow 3DS Max/Maya/Modo... questions? YES or NO?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/are-we-going-to-allow-3ds-max-maya-modo-questions-yes-or-no)

And something about technical questions if we can ever figure out as a community what to allow in that regard. But right now the only mention of technical support is next to video for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

How's about (changes in *italic*)

> - Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not
>   necessarily the "how" in logo design, fonts & typography, visual
>   communication
> - Web design as related to look and feel, not coding.
> - Layout and printing
> - Illustration
> - Type usage, theory, pairings
> - Color theory or selection
> - Composition
> - Balance
> - File formats and usage
>
>   **but not about:**
> - Simple "How to" questions *— please search your application's help files first, and do a Google search before posting a question*
> - Brainstorming or idea gathering
> - *Application Troubleshooting questions or other forms of technical support*
> - Technical questions about video editing software
> - Web site architecture and development (examples: HTML that doesn't include CSS, server-side issues)
> - Landscaping and architecture
>
> *We do accept questions about the identification of fonts, if certain conditions are met (see our guidelines for font-identification questions). The same goes for critique questions about special aspects of a design work  (see our guidelines for critique questions).*

Comment: I immediately made this a wiki, so I'd like to invite everyone to propose changes and improvements.

Comment: Just make the changes IMO. Doesn't need a group discussion when there's clearly some things that are no longer accurate on it

Comment: Well I was going to edit this.. to remove the FontID and Critique item.. while they are acceptable, I'd not promote them.. at least not the FontID in any way.  And what does "Digital Media" mean? Isn't that *everything* done on a computer?

Comment: Now that you took out "video editing software", are we accepting video editing questions on GD.SE? No where in the wiki does it say whether it is acceptable to ask questions about video editing? I just noticed 2 After Effects questions this morning. Usually I would suggest users to visit [http://video.stackexchange.com/](http://video.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Good catch, Andrew!

Comment: One of the video editing questions really had nothing to do with software which is why I was alright answering it. It could've been how to loop in Flash or animated GIF just the same. @AndrewH this is of course only my opinion

Answer (score 2):

I think leaving the wording for "Technical questions related to video editing software" is fine for off topic. It is possible to ask a design related question about a video that is not a software "how to". Whether someone asks a question like that, I don't know.

I do agree with moving 3D questions to off topic based on the points in the "Are we going to allow 3DS Max/Maya/Modo… questions? YES or NO?" thread.